# Returning a response with Ruby CGI before script is finished?

Tags: ruby, cgi

Anyone know how to send a CGI response in Ruby *before* the CGI script is finished executing?

I'm creating a fire-and-forget HTTP API.  I want a client to push data to me via HTTP and have the response return successfully, and **then** it swizzles the data and does some processing (without the client having to wait for a response).

I've tried several things that don't work, including fork.  The following will just wait 5 seconds when invoked via HTTP.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new
cgi.out "text/plain" do
  "1"
end

pid = fork
if pid
  # parent
  Process.detach pid
else
  # child
  sleep 5 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered my own question.  Turns out I just need to close $stdin, $stdout, and $stderr in the child process:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new
cgi.out "text/plain" do
  "1"
end

pid = fork
if pid
  # parent
  Process.detach pid
else
  # child
  $stdin.close
  $stdout.close
  $stderr.close
  sleep 5 
end
```

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted with `Process.daemon pid`.