# Ruby CGI redirect response without waiting end of script

Tags: ruby, http, redirect, cgi

I am developing a ruby CGI video processing tool and want to redirect the user to another location upon click on the start-ffmpeg-for-an-hour-long-encoding-spree button.

Here is the code:

```
@cgi.out("status" => "302", "location" => @job.report_url) {''}
@cgi.out{''}
@job.start
```

Doing like this works fine with Safari 5.0.5. But Firefox waits for the script to finish his work before redirecting. And, if your script takes longer to finish than Apache's timeout, it may well be never happening.

I was hoping for a kinf of cgi.close() method. Which exists! But is a CGI::Session method and has nothing to do for me.

Here is another similar question... But not a duplicate! As i need to use stdin, stdout and stderr ***after*** the redirect: [Returning a response with Ruby CGI before script is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189230)

So, how can i send a full CGI response ***before*** doing some other tasks with the same script?

Comment: Try to do @cgi.send(:stdoutput).flush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well, finally got it.**

But it looks more like a hack than a real solution:

```
@cgi.out("status" => "303", "Connection" => "close", "Content-Length" => 1, "Location" => @job.report_url) {' '}
@job.start
```

There are two keys things to make it work, both are needed:

1. Set `Content-Lenght` to something greater than 0. 1 Works well with one space of content.
2. Set `Connection` to `close`. This is awkward because this may theoretically works perfectly fine in an HTTP 1.1 Keep Alive connection. But this seems to trigger the page rendering in Firefox 4.

I've switched to a more correct 303 `See Other` response after the job submission's POST request ([HTTP 303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)). But this has no effect, it works also well with a 302 response.

Comment: connection close is required because the connection is not handled by the CGI script, is handled by the server and it will keep it open until the CGI script terminate. Also, Content-Length: 1 is weird. Content-Length: 0 with no content should work fine.

Comment: You can try closing stdout (server side connection closing) instead of setting Connection: close (client side connection closing). This will work in theory, but im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to approach this kind of problem is to seperate the application into two processes.

1. The cgi part
2. The processing part

Often the processing part is a single instance of an application waiting for messages from numerous cgi parts. The cgi part just submits requests to the processing part. The communication can be done however you like, but is often done using a job/message queue.

This way as soon as the job is submitted to the queue you can redirect the user and the processing part will eventually get around to transcoding your video.

Another advantage is that a heap of simultaneous requests will not overload your machine with dozens of concurrent transcoding operations. You can also move the processing part to one or more machines relatively easily (depending on the form of communication you choose)/

A quick [web search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=job%20queue%20ruby) will show you dozens of examples.

Comment: That's indeed the right way to handle this kind of problem. But as this application has very light and internal usage, it may be a little overkill to code a full job queue system.

Comment: I wouldn't try coding a full job queue system, most of the examples I saw were only very few lines of user code, the rest was using existing job queue systems. These two seem to be in favor with the ruby crowd: https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Comment: You're definitely right. I'll give a try to both of them. You take the bounty, as it is the right way to get around that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers (like Firefox) fill a buffer before processing data.

In home tests, I did the trick by sending 4096 spaces:

```
@cgi.out("status" => "302", "location" => @job.report_url) { ' ' * 4096 }
@job.start
```

**UPDATE:** Here is my complete test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'

# change the line below to test; e.g.: buf = ''
buf = ' ' * 4096

cgi = CGI.new
cgi.out('status' => '302', 'location' => 'http://www.example.com') { buf }

sleep 10

puts 'end'
```

Obviously, the `'end'` never appears, as browser has been redirected before.

When `buf` is empty, Firefox waits for 10s before redirect. When it's "full" (ie, 4K of spaces), the browser redirects immediately. Tested with Firefox 4.0 in Ubuntu 10.04, and Firefox 4.0.1 in Windows Seven.

Comment: Can't make it work with Firefox 4.0.1. Maybe where you using FF 3.6?

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe the `sleep` in my code is making difference? It allows more concurrency when browser AND Apache are running in the same machine, besides modern computers are prone to parallel processing. Anyway, I suggest you take a test with my code and try to adapt to your case (if my code works - please, tell me if not).

Comment: Intriguing, still doesn't work for me with FF 4.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 with Apache 2.2.17 on a separate server. But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of send an empty buffer, try setting Content-Length header to 0.
For the off request processing, Kernel#fork should help.

After a little bit of testing. This is what is need to be done. Content-Length is set properly by cgi.out. You only need to pass an empty string to set it to 0.

Also, as i stated in a comment, closing stdout effectively close the connection server side.
I tested this code with lighttpd + ree, with firefox and chrome.

```
require 'cgi'    
cgi = CGI.new
cgi.out('status' => '302', 'location' => 'http://www.google.com') { "" }
$stdout.close

# here we do a very very long task
sleep 30
exit 0
```

Comment: Doesn't work. But you put me on the right track, thanks. Specifying the Content-Length header to something greater than 0.